# Opening Folder Options window in Windows from the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments, control-panel

If I need to open the Control Panel through the command prompt, it is enough to type

```
control
```

I need to open the Folder Options window through typing some command through the command prompt.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works on Windows 7.  It may work on others.

Folder Options has three tabs.  You can choose which tab is selected when it is opened:

General Tab - `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 0`

View Tab - `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 7`

Search Tab - `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 2`

Have fun :)

Comment: How about these?  http://forums.yoosecurity.com/index.php?threads/detailed-usage-rundll32-exe.4031/

Answer (score 5):

you can open Folder Option in Run menu using This Command

> control folders